# How to adjust the position of a text on the arrow in tikzpicture? (MWE available)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, arrows

I want the text `Yes` on the arrow to be closer to the arrow. Is there a nice way to auto-adjust the text to be closer to the arrow?

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,backgrounds,fit,matrix}

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, thick, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{bubble} = [ellipse, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2em, text centered, text width=2cm, draw, fill=blue!20]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Text on Arrows}{}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm, 
                        auto, 
                        text width=3cm, 
                        scale=0.6, 
                        every node/.style={transform shape,text width=3cm}]
    
    \node (p41) [process] {root};

    \node<.(1)-> (child1) [bubble, below of=p41, xshift=-2cm] {child1};
        \draw<.(1)-> [arrow] (p41.south) -- node[anchor=south] {Yes}(child1.north);
        
    \node<.(1)-> (child2) [bubble, below of=p41, xshift=2cm] {child2};
        \draw<.(1)-> [arrow] (p41.south) -- node {No}(child2.north);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Code commented with `%<--`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,backgrounds,fit,matrix}

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, thick, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{bubble} = [ellipse, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2em, text centered, text width=2cm, draw, fill=blue!20]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Text on Arrows}{}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm, 
                        auto, 
                        %text width=3cm,%<-- this text enlarges the YES node which is 3 cm wide and thus shifts it to the left
                        scale=0.6, 
                       % every node/.style={transform shape,text width=3cm}% <-- same 
                        ]
    
    \node (p41) [process] {root};

    \node<.(1)-> (child1) [bubble, below of=p41, xshift=-2cm] {child1};
        \draw<.(1)-> [arrow] (p41.south) -- node[swap] {Yes}(child1.north);%<-- swap to change the position of auto 
        
    \node<.(1)-> (child2) [bubble, below of=p41, xshift=2cm] {child2};
        \draw<.(1)-> [arrow] (p41.south) -- node {No}(child2.north);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```